# How does this function works,

Tags: javascript, algorithm, function, ecmascript-5

Here's the code

```
var diffArray = function(a, b) {
    return b.filter(function(value) { return a.indexOf(value) === -1; });
};
```

Input is:

```
diffArray([1, "3", 3, "4"], [1, "1", 3, 4]);
```

I don't get why does it returns: `["1", 4]`

Can you please clarify that to me.

Comment: It doesn't return that. http://jsbin.com/yecanun/1/edit?js,console

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: What are you expecting the function to return and what is it actually returning?

Answer (score 0):

Explaining some things:

Array.indexOf method is a method that searches an array for a particular element and returns the index of the element if it finds it. If it didn't it returns -1.

Array.filter receives a callback function. This callback function is called once for each element of the array and it should return true if the element should be present in the filtered result or false if it shouldn't.
Example: `[1, 2, 3].filter(function(value) { return value < 3 });` would return `[1, 2]`.

So you're passing 2 arrays to diffArray. The b array is being filtered and the filter function searches a array for each element of b array and return each element of the b array that is not present in a array (every element that has indexOf === -1);

So the b elements are `[1, "1", 3, 4]`. Let's look into it step by step:

- 1 is present in a, so it's not returned because we're looking for the elements NOT present in a
- "1" is not present in a so it's returned. a array has 1 element, but that's a different type of "1'
- 3 is present is a so it's not returned
- 4 is not present in a so is returned. Again same case of different type as "1".

I hope it's clearer now.